# npm does not upgrade packages even using "--force"

Tags: npm

It seems to me that I should be able to make npm upgrade all packages to the latest version, but even after typeing "npm update --force", "npm outdated" show most of the packages are not the latest version.

Does this make sense?  Can anyone explain what's going on and how I get npm to actually update/upgrade all packages?

thanks!

```
Package                              Current          Wanted   Latest  Location
react-bootstrap               0.24.0-alpha.0  0.24.0-alpha.0   0.23.1  react-bootstrap
vinyl                                  0.4.6           0.4.6    0.5.0  gulp-sourcemaps > vinyl
vinyl                                  0.4.6           0.4.6    0.5.0  vinyl-source-stream > vinyl
vinyl-fs                              0.3.13          0.3.13    1.0.0  gulp > vinyl-fs
end-of-stream                          0.1.5           0.1.5    1.1.0  gulp > orchestrator > end-of-stream
glob                                   4.3.5           4.3.5   5.0.10  gulp > liftoff > findup-sync > glob
object-assign                          2.1.1           2.1.1    3.0.0  gulp-autoprefixer > object-assign
source-map                            0.1.43          0.1.43    0.4.2  gulp-autoprefixer > vinyl-sourcemaps-apply > source-map
es6-promise                            2.1.1           2.1.1    2.2.0  gulp-autoprefixer > postcss > es6-promise
jstransform                           10.1.0          10.1.0   11.0.1  reactify > react-tools > jstransform
glob                                   4.2.2           4.2.2   5.0.10  reactify > react-tools > commoner > glob
q                                      1.1.2           1.1.2    1.4.1  reactify > react-tools > commoner > q
recast                                0.9.18          0.9.18  0.10.12  reactify > react-tools > commoner > recast
commander                              2.5.1           2.5.1    2.8.1  reactify > react-tools > commoner > commander
minimist                               0.0.8           0.0.8    1.1.1  reactify > react-tools > commoner > mkdirp > minimist
clone                                 0.1.19          0.1.19    1.0.2  gulp-notify > node-notifier > clone
minimist                               0.2.0           0.2.0    1.1.1  gulp-notify > node-notifier > cli-usage > minimist
marked-terminal                        0.1.0           0.1.0    1.5.0  gulp-notify > node-notifier > cli-usage > marked-terminal
builtins                               0.0.7           0.0.7    1.0.1  browserify > builtins
commondir                              0.0.1           0.0.1    1.0.1  browserify > commondir
glob                                   4.5.3           4.5.3   5.0.10  browserify > glob
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  browserify > readable-stream
shell-quote                            0.0.1           0.0.1    1.4.3  browserify > shell-quote
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  browserify > through2
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  browserify > duplexer2 > readable-stream
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  browserify > deps-sort > through2
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  browserify > stream-browserify > readable-stream
date-now                               0.1.4           0.1.4    1.0.1  browserify > console-browserify > date-now
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  browserify > concat-stream > readable-stream
Base64                                 0.2.1           0.2.1    0.3.0  browserify > http-browserify > Base64
json-stable-stringify                  0.0.1           0.0.1    1.0.0  browserify > shasum > json-stable-stringify
sha.js                                 2.3.6           2.3.6    2.4.2  browserify > shasum > sha.js
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  browserify > read-only-stream > readable-stream
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  browserify > read-only-stream > readable-wrap > readable-stream
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  browserify > labeled-stream-splicer > stream-splicer > readable-stream
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  browserify > labeled-stream-splicer > stream-splicer > through2
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  browserify > labeled-stream-splicer > stream-splicer > readable-wrap > readable-stream
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  browserify > insert-module-globals > through2
combine-source-map                     0.3.0           0.3.0    0.6.1  browserify > insert-module-globals > combine-source-map
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  browserify > browser-pack > through2
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  browserify > module-deps > readable-stream
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  browserify > module-deps > through2
through2                               0.5.1           0.5.1    0.6.5  browserify > module-deps > stream-combiner2 > through2
source-map                            0.1.43          0.1.43    0.4.2  browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > source-map
estraverse                             1.9.3           1.9.3    4.1.0  browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > estraverse
esprima                                1.2.5           1.2.5    2.2.0  browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > esprima
optionator                             0.5.0           0.5.0    0.6.0  browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > optionator
esutils                                1.1.6           1.1.6    2.0.2  browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > esutils
object-assign                          2.1.1           2.1.1    3.0.0  gulp-util > object-assign
vinyl                                  0.4.6           0.4.6    0.5.0  gulp-util > vinyl
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  gulp-util > multipipe > duplexer2 > readable-stream
object-assign                          2.1.1           2.1.1    3.0.0  gulp-util > dateformat > meow > object-assign
accord                                0.15.2          0.15.2   0.19.0  gulp-less > accord
object-assign                          2.1.1           2.1.1    3.0.0  gulp-less > object-assign
source-map                            0.1.43          0.1.43    0.4.2  gulp-less > vinyl-sourcemaps-apply > source-map
promise                                6.1.0           6.1.0    7.0.1  gulp-less > less > promise
minimist                               0.0.8           0.0.8    1.1.1  gulp-less > less > mkdirp > minimist
prr                                    0.0.0           0.0.0    1.0.1  gulp-less > less > errno > prr
async                                  0.9.2           0.9.2    1.2.0  gulp-less > less > request > form-data > async
combined-stream                        0.0.7           0.0.7    1.0.3  gulp-less > less > request > form-data > combined-stream
asn1                                  0.1.11          0.1.11    0.2.2  gulp-less > less > request > http-signature > asn1
ctype                                  0.5.3           0.5.3    0.5.4  gulp-less > less > request > http-signature > ctype
jsonpointer                            1.1.0           1.1.0    2.0.0  gulp-less > less > request > har-validator > is-my-json-valid > jsonpointer
array-filter                           0.0.1           0.0.1    1.0.0  watchify > outpipe > shell-quote > array-filter
builtins                               0.0.7           0.0.7    1.0.1  watchify > browserify > builtins
commondir                              0.0.1           0.0.1    1.0.1  watchify > browserify > commondir
glob                                   4.5.3           4.5.3   5.0.10  watchify > browserify > glob
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  watchify > browserify > readable-stream
shell-quote                            0.0.1           0.0.1    1.4.3  watchify > browserify > shell-quote
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  watchify > browserify > through2
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  watchify > browserify > duplexer2 > readable-stream
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  watchify > browserify > deps-sort > through2
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  watchify > browserify > stream-browserify > readable-stream
date-now                               0.1.4           0.1.4    1.0.1  watchify > browserify > console-browserify > date-now
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  watchify > browserify > concat-stream > readable-stream
Base64                                 0.2.1           0.2.1    0.3.0  watchify > browserify > http-browserify > Base64
json-stable-stringify                  0.0.1           0.0.1    1.0.0  watchify > browserify > shasum > json-stable-stringify
sha.js                                 2.3.6           2.3.6    2.4.2  watchify > browserify > shasum > sha.js
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  watchify > browserify > labeled-stream-splicer > stream-splicer > readable-stream
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  watchify > browserify > labeled-stream-splicer > stream-splicer > through2
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  watchify > browserify > labeled-stream-splicer > stream-splicer > readable-wrap > readable-stream
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  watchify > browserify > read-only-stream > readable-stream
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  watchify > browserify > read-only-stream > readable-wrap > readable-stream
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  watchify > browserify > insert-module-globals > through2
combine-source-map                     0.3.0           0.3.0    0.6.1  watchify > browserify > insert-module-globals > combine-source-map
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  watchify > browserify > browser-pack > through2
readable-stream                       1.1.13          1.1.13   1.0.33  watchify > browserify > module-deps > readable-stream
through2                               1.1.1           1.1.1    0.6.5  watchify > browserify > module-deps > through2
through2                               0.5.1           0.5.1    0.6.5  watchify > browserify > module-deps > stream-combiner2 > through2
source-map                            0.1.43          0.1.43    0.4.2  watchify > browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > source-map
estraverse                             1.9.3           1.9.3    4.1.0  watchify > browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > estraverse
esutils                                1.1.6           1.1.6    2.0.2  watchify > browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > esutils
esprima                                1.2.5           1.2.5    2.2.0  watchify > browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > esprima
optionator                             0.5.0           0.5.0    0.6.0  watchify > browserify > module-deps > detective > escodegen > optionator
is-glob                                1.1.3           1.1.3    2.0.0  watchify > chokidar > is-glob
is-glob                                1.1.3           1.1.3    2.0.0  watchify > chokidar > glob-parent > is-glob
graceful-fs                            2.0.3           2.0.3    3.0.8  watchify > chokidar > readdirp > graceful-fs
minimatch                             0.2.14          0.2.14    2.0.8  watchify > chokidar > readdirp > minimatch
kind-of                                1.1.0           1.1.0    2.0.0  watchify > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch > kind-of
object.omit                            0.2.1           0.2.1    1.1.0  watchify > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch > object.omit
is-glob                                1.1.3           1.1.3    2.0.0  watchify > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch > is-glob
is-primitive                           1.0.0           1.0.0    2.0.0  watchify > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch > regex-cache > is-equal-shallow > is-primitive
is-glob                                1.1.3           1.1.3    2.0.0  watchify > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch > parse-glob > is-glob
is-number                              1.1.2           1.1.2    2.0.2  watchify > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch > braces > expand-range > fill-range > is-number
is-number                              1.1.2           1.1.2    2.0.2  watchify > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch > braces > expand-range > fill-range > randomatic > is-number
kind-of                                1.1.0           1.1.0    2.0.0  watchify > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch > braces > expand-range > fill-range > randomatic > kind-of
lodash                                 2.4.2           2.4.2    3.9.3  browser-sync > easy-extender > lodash
debug                                  2.1.3           2.1.3    2.2.0  browser-sync > connect > debug
finalhandler                           0.3.4           0.3.4    0.3.6  browser-sync > connect > finalhandler
request                               2.11.4          2.11.4   2.57.0  browser-sync > localtunnel > request
optimist                               0.3.4           0.3.4    0.6.1  browser-sync > localtunnel > optimist
debug                                  0.7.4           0.7.4    2.2.0  browser-sync > localtunnel > debug
async                                 0.1.15          0.1.15    1.2.0  browser-sync > portscanner > async
lodash                                 2.4.2           2.4.2    3.9.3  browser-sync > eazy-logger > opt-merger > lodash
chalk                                  0.5.1           0.5.1    1.0.0  browser-sync > eazy-logger > tfunk > chalk
is-glob                                1.1.3           1.1.3    2.0.0  browser-sync > chokidar > is-glob
is-glob                                1.1.3           1.1.3    2.0.0  browser-sync > chokidar > glob-parent > is-glob
graceful-fs                            2.0.3           2.0.3    3.0.8  browser-sync > chokidar > readdirp > graceful-fs
minimatch                             0.2.14          0.2.14    2.0.8  browser-sync > chokidar > readdirp > minimatch
escape-html                            1.0.1           1.0.1    1.0.2  browser-sync > serve-index > escape-html
angular                                1.4.0           1.4.0   1.3.16  browser-sync > browser-sync-ui > angular
connect-history-api-fallback           0.0.5           0.0.5    1.1.0  browser-sync > browser-sync-ui > connect-history-api-fallback
angular-route                          1.4.0           1.4.0   1.3.16  browser-sync > browser-sync-ui > angular-route
angular-touch                          1.4.0           1.4.0   1.3.16  browser-sync > browser-sync-ui > angular-touch
angular-sanitize                       1.4.0           1.4.0   1.3.16  browser-sync > browser-sync-ui > angular-sanitize
underscore                             1.7.0           1.7.0    1.8.3  browser-sync > browser-sync-ui > weinre > underscore
express                               2.5.11          2.5.11   4.12.4  browser-sync > browser-sync-ui > weinre > express
escape-html                            1.0.1           1.0.1    1.0.2  browser-sync > serve-static > escape-html
escape-html                            1.0.1           1.0.1    1.0.2  browser-sync > serve-static > send > escape-html
fresh                                  0.2.4           0.2.4    0.3.0  browser-sync > serve-static > send > fresh
on-finished                            2.2.1           2.2.1    2.3.0  browser-sync > serve-static > send > on-finished
crc                                    3.2.1           3.2.1    3.3.0  browser-sync > serve-static > send > etag > crc
object-assign                          2.1.1           2.1.1    3.0.0  browser-sync > meow > object-assign
is-glob                                1.1.3           1.1.3    2.0.0  browser-sync > anymatch > micromatch > is-glob
kind-of                                1.1.0           1.1.0    2.0.0  browser-sync > anymatch > micromatch > kind-of
object.omit                            0.2.1           0.2.1    1.1.0  browser-sync > anymatch > micromatch > object.omit
is-primitive                           1.0.0           1.0.0    2.0.0  browser-sync > anymatch > micromatch > regex-cache > is-equal-shallow > is-primitive
is-glob                                1.1.3           1.1.3    2.0.0  browser-sync > anymatch > micromatch > parse-glob > is-glob
is-glob                                1.1.3           1.1.3    2.0.0  browser-sync > anymatch > micromatch > parse-glob > glob-base > glob-parent > is-glob
is-number                              1.1.2           1.1.2    2.0.2  browser-sync > anymatch > micromatch > braces > expand-range > fill-range > is-number
is-number                              1.1.2           1.1.2    2.0.2  browser-sync > anymatch > micromatch > braces > expand-range > fill-range > randomatic > is-number
kind-of                                1.1.0           1.1.0    2.0.0  browser-sync > anymatch > micromatch > braces > expand-range > fill-range > randomatic > kind-of
has-binary-data                        0.1.3           0.1.3    0.1.5  browser-sync > socket.io > has-binary-data
debug                                  2.1.0           2.1.0    2.2.0  browser-sync > socket.io > debug
debug                                  0.7.4           0.7.4    2.2.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-parser > debug
json3                                  3.2.6           3.2.6    3.3.2  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-parser > json3
component-emitter                      1.1.2           1.1.2    1.2.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-parser > component-emitter
debug                                  1.0.2           1.0.2    2.2.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-adapter > debug
socket.io-parser                       2.2.2           2.2.2    2.2.4  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-adapter > socket.io-parser
object-keys                            1.0.1           1.0.1    1.0.4  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-adapter > object-keys
debug                                  1.0.3           1.0.3    2.2.0  browser-sync > socket.io > engine.io > debug
ws                                     0.5.0           0.5.0    0.7.2  browser-sync > socket.io > engine.io > ws
has-binary                             0.1.5           0.1.5    0.1.6  browser-sync > socket.io > engine.io > engine.io-parser > has-binary
blob                                   0.0.2           0.0.2    0.0.4  browser-sync > socket.io > engine.io > engine.io-parser > blob
utf8                                   2.0.0           2.0.0    2.1.0  browser-sync > socket.io > engine.io > engine.io-parser > utf8
debug                                  0.7.4           0.7.4    2.2.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > debug
component-emitter                      1.1.2           1.1.2    1.2.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > component-emitter
parseuri                               0.0.2           0.0.2    0.0.4  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > parseuri
to-array                               0.1.3           0.1.3    0.1.4  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > to-array
ws                                    0.4.31          0.4.31    0.7.2  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > ws
component-emitter                      1.1.2           1.1.2    1.2.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > component-emitter
debug                                  1.0.4           1.0.4    2.2.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > debug
has-cors                               1.0.3           1.0.3    1.1.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > has-cors
parsejson                              0.0.1           0.0.1    0.0.2  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > parsejson
parseqs                                0.0.2           0.0.2    0.0.3  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > parseqs
has-binary                             0.1.5           0.1.5    0.1.6  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > engine.io-parser > has-binary
blob                                   0.0.2           0.0.2    0.0.4  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > engine.io-parser > blob
utf8                                   2.0.0           2.0.0    2.1.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > engine.io-parser > utf8
xmlhttprequest                         1.5.0           1.5.0    1.7.0  browser-sync > socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > xmlhttprequest
```

Comment: is there a reason you want to force it? it can have unintended consequences?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are dependencies of the other node modules. Those specify which versions they would want for compatibility reasons.

With semver, if the major version changes, there are breaking changes. As an example, if ModuleA requires 1.x of ModuleB and you "force" it to use 2.1, it may not work since ModuleB has breaking changes.

Comment: Is there any way to force npm to do as it is told which is to upgrade all packages to latest?  I'm a big enough boy to understand what I'm doing.

Comment: @DukeDougal *it is doing what it is told* based on the other package.json files from the node modules.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Is there any way at all to force it to do not what is told in the packages, but what I want it to do which is upgrade everything to latest?  I'm feeling that npm is mothering me.

Comment: contact the authors other modules and ask them to upgrade?

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel. OK I hear the answer is no.  That's a pity.  It would be nice to have the software upgrade on a global basis if I command it but it seems that's not going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you really do want to update the package, you can use

```
npm install <package name>@latest
```

from the same location you ran the `npm outdated` command.

It does mean doing each one individually.